# Python Relplot with distinct lines

Tags: python, seaborn, line-plot

I want to create a plot with Seaborn by using `relplot` for the following plot:

[image]

My code so far is:

```
f = sns.relplot(
    data = data,
    x="year",
    y="gdpPercap",
    hue="continent",
    col="continent",
    col_wrap=3,
    height=2,
    aspect=1.5,
    alpha=0.5,
    kind="line",
)

for ax in f.axes.flatten():
    ax.semilogy()
```

However, my plot looks like this:

[image]

How do I change the plot so that each line represent each data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `units` to draw a separate line without any additional semantic mapping:

```py
g = sns.relplot(
    data=gapminder,
    kind="line",
    x="year",
    y="gdpPercap",
    hue="continent",
    col="continent",
    units="country",
    estimator=None,
    col_wrap=3,
    height=3,
    alpha=0.5,
)
g.set(yscale="log")
```

[image]

PS note that it is not necessary to loop over the axes to get a log-scaled y axis...